# The following angular template driven form doesnt give an error in the browser, but it underlines in red color in vs code

Tags: angular

This is the code segment witch leads to =>Identifier 'email' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" [(ngModel)]= "email" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
```

This is the component.ts file

```
export class CreateEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {



  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  saveEmployee(empForm:NgForm):void{
console.log(empForm.value);
  }

}
```

What is wrong with the above code? A helpful answer is really appreciated

Comment: I have added it now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is giving you that error as `email` is not a defined variable in your **TS** file

```
export class CreateEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  email: string; //declare variable

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  saveEmployee(empForm:NgForm):void{
    console.log(empForm.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: That helped. I have totally missed it...  but I want to know one thing that why it does not give an error in the browser console?

Comment: It should once you save it or HMR kicks in and will show you error on the window itself